# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^{b} ne^{-n |t|} dt$

Tags: integration, limits

I think that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^{b} ne^{-n |t|} dt= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} -e^{-n |b|} + e^{-n |a|} = 0 + 0 = 0$$

But the solution for this problems claims:

> if a < 0, b > 0, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^{b} ne^{-n |t|} dt = 2$
>
> if a > 0, b > 0, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^{b} ne^{-n |t|} dt = 0$
>
> if b > 0, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{b} ne^{-n |t|} dt = 1$

What do you think?

Comment: Substitute $u = n\cdot t$.

Comment: But I have |t|, not t.

Comment: Well, since $n \geqslant 0$, we have $n\lvert t\rvert = \lvert nt\rvert$.

Comment: $\int ne^{-|nt|} dt = \int e^{-|u|} du = -e^{-|u|}$, so what? the result is the same.

Comment: Why is the antiderivative incorrect?

Comment: Beacuse $e^{-\lvert u\rvert}$ is not differentiable in $0$. But, if you had not removed the integral bounds, you would see that - and why - the limits are as stated.

Comment: @DavidMitra $\operatorname{sign}(x)\bigl(1-e^{-\lvert x\rvert}\bigr)$.

Comment: OK, I understand this now.

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course, thanks. Deleting...